# Sensitivity or scenario based analysis in anylogic (DES model)

Tags: analysis, anylogic

I have different resources in my DES model, when I change the values of these resources my outputs will also change.

Please, how can I perform this kind of operation (the sensitivity analysis), such that I declare all the changes once and the different outputs will be automatically generated to an excel file?

I have used the "parameter variation experiment" function to create an experiment, but I am still getting an error. Please, see the screenshot attached.

[image]

I have some parameters that I would like to declare a range of value for, and get the outputs based on the range (i.e., when the parameter value of each element is 1, 2 and 3 - see the screenshot).

Thanks.

Comment: Use parameters variation experiment

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions on *how to solve a problem*, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question is a generic “how do I best do X” question. This is too broad for SOF and better asked in a forum like LinkedIn. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions here: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Welcome again, we are all happy to help on specifics :)

Comment: Okay.

I have used the "parameter variation experiment" function to create an experiment, but I am still getting an error. Please, see the screenshot attached.

I have some parameters that I would like to declare a range of value for, and get the outputs based on the range (i.e., when the parameter value of each element is 1, 2 and 3 - see the screenshot).

Thanks.

Comment: Double click on the error and see where it takes you - it is somewhere where you are trying to add a data set to the chart.